# How to get texts from an url of tweets in Python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweets

I have an url of tweet and want to get texts of tweet from the url in Python. But I have no idea. I searched about Tweepy, But I think It's for search, upload tweets not to get texts from url.

Comment: requests and beautiful soup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use Beautiful Soup to grab the info you need via cURL.  They have decent documentation. Does Twitter have an API you could use?